Memory management / How to set OpenCLMemory a new value
According to the official documentation, we have only
OpenCLMemoryAllocate
OpenCLMemoryLoad
both of them return a new pointer even for the same value
test = {{0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4}, {0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4}};
OpenCLMemoryLoad[test, "Float[4]"]
OpenCLMemoryLoad[test, "Float[4]"]

OpenCLMemory["<2039965573>","Float[4]"]
OpenCLMemory["<1124961056>","Float[4]"]

Does it mean, that if I want to load a new data to the same pointer, I have to reallocate it using OpenCLMemoryLoad (and purge previous one using OpenCLMemoryUnload)? I assume it will be horribly slow
I am expecting somewhat similar to memcpy called OpenCLMemorySet, so that my machine does not have to spend extra resources to create buffers and etc.
Why is it possible to reuse the old memory if you output the data or pipe it though different kernels, but not for the input?
It completely kills the applications of OpenCLLink for video or audio processing, or rendering if we cannot reload any OpenCLMemory.

You're using it wrong. From the docs: OpenCLMemoryAllocate is used when memory needs to be allocated to be written to, such as output memory. - Allocate memory for outputs. You don't need to allocate inputs.

My sympathies Indeed, it is strange that something like OpenCLMemorySet does not exist. However, if I read the documentation right, OpenCLMemoryLoad and OpenCLMemory do not allocate memory on the GPU, only in the CPU's memory. That is of the same speed (or slowness) as using an ordinary Mathematica tensor. Only if the memory is really used by some OpenCL funciton or if you explicitly call OpenCLMemoryCopyToDevice, the memory will actually be allocated on the GPU and data is transferred.

I think this is why the developers decided that OpenCLMemorySet would not be worth it. Either you load a already prepared array in one chunk. Then OpenCLMemoryLoad does the trick. Or you want to modify the array's entry one by one in a loop. Then the allocation cost can be neglected anyways (because loops are slow in top level Mathematica). So there is no big harm in using OpenCLMemoryLoad, too.

In any case, if GPU and CPU do not use the same physical memory (e.g. "Unified Memory" in Apple lingo), then OpenCLMemoryCopyToDevice and OpenCLMemoryCopyToHost will be the bottlenecks anyway; allocation won't matter much.

I see. I though it was exactly malloc called on GPU side ;D Thank you, @flinty and @henrik-schumacher
Now it makes sense. What I also noticed, If i pass directly some array to a function
openCLFunction[test, 32] //is a bit faster
than
mem = OpenCLMemoryLoad[test, "Float[4]"];
openCLFunction[mem, 32]
OpenCLMemoryUnload[test];
When it comes to large chunks of data. But as  @flinty mentioned, it is recommended in docs

Indeed OpenCLMemoryLoad allocates pinned memory region (somewhat similar we have in C/C++ and CUDA) to work with GPU

Closed. As it was mentioned in comments

You're using it wrong. From the docs: OpenCLMemoryAllocate is used when memory needs to be allocated to be written to, such as output memory. - Allocate memory for outputs. You don't need to allocate inputs.


However, if I read the documentation right, OpenCLMemoryLoad and OpenCLMemory do not allocate memory on the GPU, only in the CPU's memory. That is of the same speed (or slowness) as using an ordinary Mathematica tensor. Only if the memory is really used by some OpenCL funciton or if you explicitly call OpenCLMemoryCopyToDevice, the memory will actually be allocated on the GPU and data is transferred.

